# SQL DISTINCT for 2 Columns WHERE 3rd column = value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to Select the Count of Distinct Columns Col 1 & Col 2 Where Col 3 = "Complete".

Firstly I don't know how to make Distinct apply to Col 1 & Col 2 together as opposed to Distinct about their own columns.
Secondly how to exclude Col 3 from the Distinct..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count From 
(Select Distinct DP, RN From ECount 
Where ET = 'Complete') as rows
```

Any thoughts?

example

```
col1    col2    col3    
DP01    RN01    Complete    yes
DP01    RN02    Incomplete  
DP02    RN03    Complete    
DP02    RN03    Incomplete  
DP01    RN04    Complete    yes
DP02    RN05    Complete    yes
DP03    RN06    Incomplete
```

Result = 3

Comment: can you give table structure with data and sample output?

Comment: Hi, See updated table and expected result.

Comment: @C.Koo, I tried the update but i 'm still getting a result of 4 when i'm expecting a result of 3 for the above table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to include Column 3 (aka, col `ET`) in the `SELECT` part, you can just use it in the `WHERE` statement directly.

So in your example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT DP, RN FROM ECount 
   WHERE ET = 'Complete'
  ) AS rows
```

Answer (score 0):

just don't select ET in subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
From  ( 
        Select Distinct DP, RN 
        From ECount 
        Where ET = 'Complete'
) as rows
```

Comment: Yes sorry that shouldnt have been there. My issue is getting the Distinct to apply to the DP and RN together, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Count(*) AS Count
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    `ECount`
                ORDER BY
                    col3 DESC
            ) AS StrongIncomplete
        GROUP BY
            col1,
            col2
    ) AS CompleteCut
WHERE
    CompleteCut.col3 = 'Complete'
```

There are 3 `SELECT` statements.

The first one rearranges the table that 'Incomplete' is prior than 'Complete' in Col3.

The second one removes rows duplicated in Col1, Col2.

The third one removes rows where Col3 = 'Incomplete'

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your code but i got a similar result which isn't what i'm trying to achieve. I have added an example and the expected result  to the original post. If you see my table DP02 RN03 shouldn't be included as they are found elsewhere in the table.